# How to stop alt key from triggering vscode's menus bar on linux?

Tags: visual-studio-code, alt-key

When using VSCode on eOS, the menus on the title bar is pretty annoying if I hold the <kbd>alt</kbd> key or use some keyboard shortcut like <kbd>shif + alt + RightArrow</kbd>. So, how can we stop this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below settings to hide the menus:

```
{
  "window.titleBarStyle": "custom"，
  "window.menuBarVisibility": "hidden",
  "window.customMenuBarAltFocus": false
}
```